# How do I get Genesis to open a different mobile menu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm using the WordPress [Genesis Framework](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/) and I have created a separate mobile menu (as I had to split the desktop one in two) and I'm using the built-in responsive menu it has, but I cannot figure out how to get Genesis to open the new mobile menu I created rather than the primary one.

Is there some way you can provide a different selector/id so Genesis knows to target a different menu?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new menu, you give it a name.  Let's say we name it 'footer menu 1'.  When you add this menu to your page (either through php or through the Custom Menu Widget), it will get a `ul` with id = "menu-footer-menu-1".  You can use that to target the menu.

The built-in responsive menu I've seen with genesis is to have the menu items flow to multiple lines if the screen gets too small.  Many of the Genesis child themes, though, include some javascript to turn the menu into a hamburger icon at certain window widths.  You'll have to check your child theme files to see.

I would put both the desktop menu and the mobile menu in your markup and use media queries (or javascript) to hide the respective menu depending on the width of the window.